# Ruby - Allowed/restrict Url access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up something that allows users to go to certain urls only under certain circumstances. Right now I have a `setEvent/:id` url that sets a property on users to an `event_id`, then redirects the user to the `event` url. The user can access a url like `.../whatever/event/1` where `1` needs to equal the `event_id`, and if it doesn't it redirects the user.

However, this doesn't stop someone from just typing `.../whatever/setEvent/:id` into their address bar to get access to the page.

Comment: have a look at cancancan gem

Comment: or just test to see if the user making the request is the one that created the event (in case you store an user_id in the Event table, or have a many to many relations between those 2 entities.)

Comment: Well, the events are all created by an admin, they are just shown to the users at certain times. The `setEvent` method just sets which event the user is seeing, so I can't check if the user created the event.

Comment: add more info, for example the action that is triggered by setEvent/:id. Without knowing what are you doing I guess that an user will go to `setEvent/:id`, this will subscribe them to the event, then you save this data somewhere (we don't know where), if all of that is right, all you need to do is a `before_action:` that checks the `user_id` against the saved data.

Comment: Clicking a link sends the user to `setEvent/:id` which sets an `event_id` property on the user, then redirects them to `event/:id` which checks the `event_id` on the user against the `param[:id]` of the event page and redirects the user away if they dont match up. if they do match up then it removes the `event_id` from the user so they can't refresh to the same page. The problem with that is that nothing stops the user from just manually typing `setEvent/#` into the address bar.

Comment: One way of preventing that, is to give them(your users) a token so when they have to set an event you will validate that token first.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is with a before action in your controllers. Here is an example from one of my apps where a user who is not logged in will always be redirected to the new_session URL.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :herd_user


  def herd_user
    redirect_to new_session_url unless logged_in?
  end

  ... other medthods...

end
```

and

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :herd_user

  def index

  end
end
```

Comment: What if they are logged in and go to a url they shouldn't be allowed to go to?

Comment: That URL would get them to a specific controller action. In that method, check group membership of the current user and redirect as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

without bringing in more gems you can just do a before_action

```
before_action :enforce_tenancy, except: [:index]
before_action :allow_only_admin, only: [:index]

private 

def enforce_tenancy
  render unauthorized unless event.user_id == current_user.id
end

def allow_only_admin
  render no_way_sucka_path unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: See my comment on the original question.

Comment: Using this will work if you set the before action to enforce the logic on the actions you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this might not be the best way to handle it but in the action for that page you can check the current url and check the property then redirect to the one they can access if they go to an incorrect url.

Something kind of like:

```
url_id = request.fullpath.sub('/whatever/event/', '')
redirect_to user_page_path(user.id) unless (current_user.event_id.to_s == url_id)
```

Sorry if the code isn't great I tried to write it based off of the info you gave.

Edit* Make sure to do this before getting any info for the page from your database or it will be less efficient.